# Having trouble with configure.ac syntax using AC_SEARCH_LIBS

Tags: autoconf

I'm trying to use AC_SEARCH_LIBS to find the location of the X libraries on my system. Some older systems (RH4) have the libraries in /usr/X11, while most current systems just put them in /usr/lib.

I tried the following hoping that it would add -L/usr/X11R6 to LDFLAGS only if needed:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([XFree], [X11], [], [
  LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64"
  AC_MSG_CHECKING["Looking for XFree in /usr/X11R6"]
  AC_SEARCH_LIBS([XFree], [X11], [], [
    AC_MSG_FAILURE(["Cannot find X11. Try setting LDFLAGS -L"], [-1])
  ])
])
```

but I get syntax errors from the generated configure script:

```
./configure: line 15546: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./configure: line 15546: `fi'
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using the presupplied macros `AC_PATH_X` or `AC_PATH_XTRA`?

Comment: No. I didn't know about them, but I will use them.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to look at line 15546 of `configure` first thing. The error is often immediately obvious, even if you're not that good at shell script.

That said, I'd guess that it was the lack of parentheses after `AC_MSG_CHECKING`, try this:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([Looking for XFree in /usr/X11R6])
```

Comment: I looked in the configure script and saw two 'fi's in a row, but it was too complicated to track all the matching ifs.

Comment: You're probably right about the lack of (), but since yesterday, I've discovered that the values from AC_SEARCH_LIBS are cached and if you call it twice the second call doesn't actually check, so I've had to switch to whole other scheme. Thanks for the answer though.